# PYSNMP 4.4.12- Cannot compile custom MIBs

Tags: python, ansible, pysnmp

I'm struggling to load custom MIBs in my first attempt at pysnmp. I have read that the old versions required a compiling of the custom mibs, and the newer versions embed the compiling in backend processes. When I try either method, the script just hangs ... indefinitely. The custom MIB is CISCO-PRODUCTS.MIB which I have downloaded and ends with a .my extension.

```
python3 mibdump.py  --mib-source=file://./ --destination-directory=/home/myuser/Desktop/Ansible/mibs --destination-format=pysnmp  CISCO-PRODUCTS-MIB

Source MIB repositories: file://./  Borrow missing/failed MIBs from:
http://mibs.snmplabs.com/pysnmp/notexts/@mib@  
Existing/compiled MIB locations: pysnmp.smi.mibs, pysnmp_mibs  
Compiled MIBs destination directory: /home/myuser/Desktop/Ansible/mibs  
MIBs excluded from code generation: INET-ADDRESS-MIB, PYSNMP-USM-MIB, RFC-1212, RFC-1215, RFC1065-SMI, RFC1155-SMI, RFC1158-MIB, RFC1213-MIB, SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB, SNMP-TARGET-MIB, SNMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC, SNMPv2-TM, TRANSPORT-ADDRESS-MIB  
MIBs to compile: CISCO-PRODUCTS-MIB  
Destination format: pysnmp  
Parser grammar cache directory: not used  
Also compile all relevant MIBs: yes  
Rebuild MIBs regardless of age: no  
Dry run mode: no  
Create/update MIBs: yes  
Byte-compile Python modules: yes (optimization level no)  
Ignore compilation errors: no  
Generate OID->MIB index: no  
Generate texts in MIBs: no  
Keep original texts layout: no  
Try various file names while searching for MIB module: yes
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mibdump.py", line 350, in
<module>
    processed = mibCompiler.compile(   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysmi/compiler.py",
line 227, in compile
    fileInfo, fileData = source.getData(mibname)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysmi/reader/localfile.py",
line 105, in getData
    for path in self.getSubdirs(self._path, self._recursive, self._ignoreErrors):   File
"/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysmi/reader/localfile.py",
line 64, in getSubdirs
    dirs.extend(self.getSubdirs(d, recursive))   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysmi/reader/localfile.py",
line 64, in getSubdirs
    dirs.extend(self.getSubdirs(d, recursive))   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysmi/reader/localfile.py",
line 64, in getSubdirs
    dirs.extend(self.getSubdirs(d, recursive))   [Previous line repeated 44 more times]   File
"/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysmi/reader/localfile.py",
line 63, in getSubdirs
    if os.path.isdir(d):   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py", line 42, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s) KeyboardInterrupt
```

The files in the same directory are:

- CISCO-PRODUCTS-MIB.my
- CISCO-SMI.my
- mibdump.py
- SNMPv2-CONF.my
- SNMPv2-SMI.my
- SNMPv2-TC.my

Does anyone know where the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--mib-searcher` argument solves the issue`

```sh
mibdump.py --disable-fuzzy-source --mib-source /home/user/.snmp/mibs --mib-searcher=/home/user/.snmp/mibs --destination-format pysnmp [MIB_ MODULE]
```

where *[MIB_MODULE].mib* file presents in */home/user/.snmp/mibs* directory

Reference: https://snmplabs.thola.io/pysmi/mibdump.html